# Why do I receive error TypeError: argument of type 'Name' is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, class, oop

I am putting a class for a column in pandas, but my error says:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'Name' is not iterable
```

I don't understand why, I tried making a forloop that returns "pass".
Here is my code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        list = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")
        self.name = self.Name()

    class Name:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = list(['Name'].str.lower())
            for i in list:
                pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    person = Person()
    checking_name = str(input()).lower()
    list = person.name

    if(checking_name in list):
        print("Hit")
```

Error is on my last if statement:
Any ideas?

Comment: `list` is keyword(reserved word).

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @Shakeel: btw, I’m told it is a built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying to iterate in `list` which is the built-in `python` function to change data into a list. Even when you place there `pass` it will iterate in the background.

Comment: so are you saying it will iterate? why do i receive an error that it is not iterating? should i put it in a list outside of the class?

Comment: because the python wants to iterate, but it can not - the `list` is not a variable - it is a keyword.

Comment: @Hernandez did it help you?

Comment: @Hernandez can you please upvote and accept my answer?